# VBA code restarting halfway through without error message

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have the below code it seems to work fine however halfway through it, it stops and restarts when I am debugging the code.

When it restarts is does not show any error message. Does anyone know why my code is doing this?

```
Sub ExportPICs()

If FileIsOpen("U:\FBS\PROJECTS_TEAM\MI\Sean's Projects\PICS and Benefits\Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm") Then
    MsgBox "That file's open, or doesn't exist - do something else."
    Exit Sub
    End If

Sheets("Post Implementation Costs").Visible = True
Sheets("Post Implementation Costs").Activate
Sheets("Post Implementation Costs").Unprotect Password:="Projects123"

Dim Tracker As String
Tracker = ThisWorkbook.Name

Dim wkbk As Excel.Workbook
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
"U:\FBS\PROJECTS_TEAM\MI\Sean's Projects\PICS and Benefits\Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm") '***********CODE RESTARTS HERE WITHOUT ERROR MESSAGE

Dim pics As String
pics = Dir("U:\FBS\PROJECTS_TEAM\MI\Sean's Projects\PICS and Benefits\Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm")


Workbooks(Tracker).Activate
Sheets("Post Implementation Costs").Activate

Dim rng As Range
Dim CountTrue As Long
Set rng = Range("D16:D100")
CountTrue = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "PIC")

If CountTrue > 0 Then
Rows("19:" & (CountTrue + 18)).EntireRow.Copy
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If their any code in the open event of Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm?

Comment: No the "Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm" is currently macro free.

Comment: How do you trigger this code?

Comment: I trigger this code within a different file - Referenced within the code "Tracker File"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any code in the Workbook Open Event in "Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm" that would do the Loop.

Try `Application.EnableEvents = False`

before

```
Dim wkbk As Excel.Workbook
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= _
"U:\FBS\PROJECTS_TEAM\MI\Sean's Projects\PICS and Benefits\Pics & Benefits upload file.xlsm")
```

And after that you can activate it again via `Application.EnableEvents = True`

This code stops Excel event handlers from being called. Setting it to false is usually done because the effect of the event handler is undesirable or to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: I have an open workbook event within the file which is running the macro but not in the Workbook I am opening with this line of code. Unfortunately the event handler line did not work :(

Comment: I have worked adapted your solution slightly and placed the      Application.EnableEvents = False

Within the macro held on the second page. this has resolved the issue thanks for your help!! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered too that with some statements the Step command doesn't step but lets all the following code run. To avoid this, set a breakpoint at the line following where the step gets confused.

Comment: How strange, that seemed to work :) My knowledge of breakpoints is limited is there any way of making them permanent as when I close the file and re-open it the breakpoint disappears which consequently makes the issue re-appear.

Comment: You could use the "Stop" statement

Comment: Thanks, my macro is password protected though :( is there anyway of getting around this I.e. using the stop statement and the Macro restarting itself without my colleagues going into the Module.